# How do I change the navbar height in bootstrap? (Link included)

Tags: css, height, navbar

I'm learning basic HTML, CSS, and PHP. To test my skills, I do the simplest of tasks and try to create something new. I've been trying to alter the height of this Bootstrap template, but nothing seems to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Link: http://demo.themeineed.com/free-dashboard-template/klorofil/elements.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you've only linked to documentation on a theme. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all of **your** code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering the height in bootstrap is normally not necessary since all the items height will be automaticly adjusted when new content is added. If you do want to add custom heights to some objects you could do this by simply adding some custom CSS to your stylesheet e.g.

```
.main-content {
   min-height: 500px;
}
```

**Full simple example**

```css
div.example {
background-color: green
}

div.exampleHeight {
background-color: yellow;
height: 200px;
}

div.exampleHeightTwo {
background-color: lightgrey;
min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 example">
  <p>
  Hello
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 exampleHeight">
  <p>
  Added normal height element
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 exampleHeightTwo">
  <p>
  Added minimal height element
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your custom.css page and change the number value

```
.navbar-inner {
 min-height: 40px; 
 }
```